# How to fix bad Double-Buffering

Tags: java, graphics, awt, flicker, double-buffering

I tried following a double buffering tutorial, and I really don't know what I did wrong. It works before then before I did the tutorial, but there is still and occasional flicker here and there. I have two files Game and gameLoop

Game:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
public class Game extends gameLoop
{
    public void init()
    {
        setSize(854,480);
        Thread th = new Thread(this);
        th.start();
        offscreen = createImage(854,480);
        d = offscreen.getGraphics();
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        d.clearRect(0, 0, 854, 480);
        d.drawImage(disk, x, y, this);
        g.drawImage(offscreen , 0, 0, this);
    }
    public void Update(Graphics gfx)
    {
        paint(gfx);
    }
}
```

gameLoop

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.PointerInfo;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class gameLoop extends Applet implements Runnable, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener 
{
    public int x, y, counter, mouseX, mouseY;
    public Image offscreen;
    public Graphics d;
    public boolean up, down, left, right, pressed;
    public BufferedImage disk1, disk2, disk3, disk4, disk;
    public int ballSpeedX = -6;
    public int ballSpeedY = -3;

    public void run() 
    {
        x = 400;
        y = 200;
        try {
            disk1 = ImageIO.read(new File("disk1.png"));
            disk2 = ImageIO.read(new File("disk2.png"));
            disk3 = ImageIO.read(new File("disk3.png"));
            disk4 = ImageIO.read(new File("disk4.png"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        while(true)
        {
            if(x >= (854 - 150))
            {
                    ballSpeedX = ballSpeedX * -1;
            }
            if(y >= (480 - 140))
            {
                    ballSpeedY = ballSpeedY * -1;
            }
            if(y < (0 - 10))
            {
                    ballSpeedY = ballSpeedY * -1;
            }
            if(x < (0- 10))
            {
                    ballSpeedX = ballSpeedX * -1;
            }

            x = x + ballSpeedX;
            y = y + ballSpeedY;

            counter ++;
            if(counter >= 4)
                counter = 0;

            if(counter == 0)
                disk = disk1;
            if(counter == 1)
                disk = disk2;
            if(counter == 2)
                disk = disk3;
            if(counter == 3)
                disk = disk4;

            System.out.println(counter);

            repaint();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(30);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }



    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent m) {}

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent m) 
    {

    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent m) 
    {
        pressed = false;
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
        Point b  = a.getLocation();
        mouseX = (int)b.getX();
        mouseY = (int)b.getY();
        ballSpeedX = mouseX;
        ballSpeedY = mouseY;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use AWT in the 3rd millennium?  Here we use Swing (or possibly later toolkits).

Comment: ^^ As above. If you use JFrame, and JPanel, you will find that you can use `setDoubledBuffered(true)`, which I think does double buffering automatically.

Comment: Its a school assignment, I have to do it this way with an applet.

Comment: Shouldn't `Update(Graphics gfx)` be lower case? As you're trying to override the update function in the applet?

Comment: .... wow I can't believe I missed that, I completely forgot about that method. Thank you, that worked!

Answer (score 2):

```
public void Update(Graphics gfx)
{
    paint(gfx);
}
```

Should be lower case, as you're trying to override the `update(Graphics g)` method in the Applet.

So it should be

```
@Override
public void update(Graphics gfx)
{
    paint(gfx);
}
```

As for changing the background, a background is simply a big rectangle that covers the screen and makes it a certain color. In your `paint`, you're doing `clearRect`, which clears the screen. Instead just switch that to `fillRect` after setting the color.

It might look something like

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    //setColor to whatever you want
    //fillRect to cover the screen
}
```

When you're doing this though, one thing you have to remember is to not confuse your two graphics objects. As a concept, double buffering works by drawing to memory first (drawing it on an offscreen image) and then to the screen. You want to always draw onto this offscreen image, as it is much faster (and we lose the flicker).

So make sure you're doing `imageGraphicsObject.setColor` not `screenGraphicsObject.setColor` or imageGraphicsObject.fillRect`not`screenGraphicsObject.fillRect`. Otherwise you're no longer double-buffering.

Comment: Yeah, that fixed. One more question, how would I change the background color on this applet?

Comment: I'm seriously confused, the default implementation of `update` simply calls `paint` any way, there should be no need to even override it...

Comment: @MadProgrammer This is what I've been told http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/ui/drawing/update.html

Comment: A good prompt to use `@Override` notation.

Comment: @Clark You're right, I dug to deep into the class hierarchy, `Container` overrides the default implementation and clears the background, nice to know :D

Comment: @user2259774 To change the background, I would paint it to your backing buffer as the image painting can be faster

Comment: @MadProgrammer how would I do that? I am sorry for all these questions but I just started doing graphics and applet work yesterday.

Comment: @user2259774 Basically, before you paint anything else onto you buffer, basically set the color you want through `Graphics#setColor(Color)` and then fill it by calling `Graphics#fillRect(x, y, width, height)`

Comment: @MadProgrammer would I do this in my paint()?

Comment: @user2259774 Given that's where you're updating you graphics, then I'd say yes

Comment: @MadProgrammer

When I do that the background flickers between black and white.

Comment: @user2259774 My concern is I don't think you really understand double buffering

Comment: @MadProgrammer I get that basics behind it, but I don't really get the implementation.

Comment: @MadProgrammer so besides putting those two lines of code in my paint what else do I need to do? I guessing it has something to do with        offscreen = createImage(854,480);      d = offscreen.getGraphics();

Comment: I see when explained that way it makes much more sense thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of different types "double buffers".  The basic is a simple off screen image that you update and this gets painted to the screen instead.  If done right, painting the image is often faster then drawing graphics to the screen.

Another type is page flipping.  That is, you have an active buffer which is always rendered to the screen and a off screen/scratch buffer which is what you actually render to.  You then flip these buffers when you are ready to render the updates to the screen (this is closer to how film animation works).

The following example is a REALLY basic example of page flipping.

[image]

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import static testdoublebuffer.TestDoubleBuffer.UPDATE;

public class AppletDoubleBuffer extends Applet {

    private BufferedPane pane;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        pane = new BufferedPane();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(pane);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        pane.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        pane.stop();
    }

    public class BufferedPane extends Panel {

        private BufferedImage activeBuffer;
        private BufferedImage scratch;
        private boolean running = false;

        public BufferedPane() {
        }

        public void start() {
            if (!running) {
                running = true;
                Thread thread = new Thread(new MainLoop());
                thread.setDaemon(true);
                thread.start();
            }
        }

        public void stop() {
            running = false;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        public void invalidate() {
            synchronized (UPDATE) {
                activeBuffer = null;
                scratch = null;
            }
            super.invalidate();
        }

        @Override
        public void update(Graphics g) {
            if (activeBuffer != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                g2d.drawImage(activeBuffer, 0, 0, this);
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }

        public class MainLoop implements Runnable {

            private int delay = 1000 / 25;
            private int x = 0;
            private int velocity = 5;
            private int size = 10;

            public void update() {

                x += velocity;
                if (x + size >= getWidth()) {
                    x = getWidth() - size;
                    velocity *= -1;
                } else if (x <= 0) {
                    x = 0;
                    velocity *= -1;
                }

                if (getWidth() > 0 && getHeight() > 0) {
                    synchronized (UPDATE) {
                        if (scratch == null) {
                            scratch = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                        }
                        Graphics2D g2d = scratch.createGraphics();
                        int y = (getHeight() - size) / 2;
                        g2d.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                        g2d.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                        g2d.fillOval(x, y, size, size);
                        g2d.dispose();

                        // Flip the buffers...
                        BufferedImage tmp = activeBuffer;
                        activeBuffer = scratch;
                        scratch = tmp;
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (running) {

                    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    update();
                    repaint();

                    long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                    if (duration < delay) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(delay);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I personally, would just skip using AWT and move to Swing which provides better/built in functionality for this type of thing.

Comment: I would to skip AWT but its part of the course so I have do do it.

Comment: @user2259774 I'd say it's a bad course.  No doubt you need to have an understanding of AWT and how Swing builds on it, but that's just my opinion ;)

Comment: We will be moving on the swing in a few days but this is the only programming course that is offered at my school at a grade 11 level, I can tell you it's much better than the grade 10 course as we had to use Visual Basic 6 in the grade 10 course.